# Nodata use with parentgrp

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am using parentgrp to organize tab data. I have 4 tabs. I have an array of data sorted by status (which correlates with the tab name...active inactive etc). Was wondering the best way to display a no data message if one of the groups has no data. I don't see how this is possible since TBS wouldn't know what the groups actually are. Its just switching everytime it sees a change. Is there a way to do this without changing my approach.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data for a group, then it is not seen by parameter `parentgrp` since this parameter leans on the data only.

Si I can see two way to performs what you look for :

1) insert a row for each missing expected group in your data.

or

2) if there is a fixed list of expected groups, then use conditional display sections, or even sub-block, instead of using `parentgrp`.